# SQL Server In-Memory OLTP Hash Index set value for BUCKET_COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

When creating a hash index in memory optimization table I can set value for variable `BUCKET_COUNT`

```
CREATE TABLE [Table1] (
[Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED HASH 
                                WITH (BUCKET_COUNT = 1000000),
[Name] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
) 
WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON, DURABILITY = SCHEMA_AND_DATA);
```

What is the optimal value for this variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Determining the Correct Bucket Count for Hash Indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn494956%28v=sql.120%29):

> In most cases the bucket count **should be between 1 and 2 times the
> number of distinct values in the index key**. If the index key contains
> a lot of duplicate values, on average there are more than 10 rows for
> each index key value, use a nonclustered index instead
>
> You may not always be able to predict how many values a particular index key may have or will have. **Performance should be acceptable if the BUCKET_COUNT value is within 5 times of the actual number of key values.**

And:

> **Primary Key** and Unique Indexes
>
> Because the primary key index is unique, **the number of distinct values in the key corresponds to the number of rows in the table.**